# Dealing with a class that has organically grown too large

Tags: java

*Disclaimer: This is live, production code for my hobby project: [LSML (GitHub)](https://github.com/EmilyBjoerk/lsml). Due to the size of the code I'm unable to include everything in this review.*

The application is a tool for configuring loadouts for an online mech game.

## Brief summary of the problem domain

A mech has 8 components: Head, Lt/Rt/C Torso, Lt/Rt Leg and Lt/Rt Arm that each can be individually configured with equipment and armor.

A mech's effectiveness (discounting tactics and strategy of the player) is defined by what equipment it has and how it is distributed.

This software allows creation of different loadouts with equipment and armor and performing statistical analysis on them.

### Constraints

There are three main constraint types on loadouts.

- Space (Slots) - Equipment occupy space, and space is limited in components.
- Weight (Mass) - The mech has a max carrying capacity which must not be exceeded.
- Hard points - Certain equipment require the presence of a matching hard point on the component to be equippable.

Hard points and maximum weight is defined by a chassis. Each chassis has different characteristics when it comes to movement, hard points, and other constraints.

### Upgrades

A mech can have so called "upgrades" which affect global properties of the mech. For example the internal structure can be "standard" or "endo-steel" where endo steel is a space/mass trade off. Similarily other upgrades for mech's cooling, armor and missile guidance can be installed that will affect the performance of the mech.

### Modifiers and weapon groups

It is worth noting that many attributes of items and the mech can be altered by modifiers. These may be anything from special equipment that enhances some properties of other equipment, to player level (called Efficiencies) based.

Weapons can also be grouped and fired in groups. This is a vital part of game play and effective piloting, these weapon groups are modeled and statistics are calculated per group.

**All of the above, weapon groups, player skill levels (efficiencies), upgrades, equipment, armor distribution, modifiers and chassis make up the loadout.**

## Problem with the code

The class I have for representing the loadout has grown organically over several years from what started as a small class to something that is turning into quite a beast.

It has been complicated by the fact that there are two types of chassis with slightly different rules for the loadouts: Omni Mechs and Standard Mechs. Which was not originally thought of when the class was designed but has been added in as an after-the-fact. Omni Mechs have fixed equipment that can't be moved and fixed engine and upgrades, but they allow you to change between several "omnipods" per component that alters the set of hardpoints the component supports, giving more freedom in design.

I'm happy for any feedback, but I'm mostly interested in suggestions for how I can manage this unwieldy beast.

If you need to see the rest of the code, it is available in the github repository linked at the top.

> LoadoutBase.java - Abstract Base class for Omni- and Standard-Loadouts

```
/**
 * This class acts as a common base for loadouts for both Omni- and Standard- Battle 'Mechs.
 * 
 * @author Emily Björk
 * @param <T>
 *            The type of the {@link ConfiguredComponentBase} in this loadout.
 */
public abstract class LoadoutBase<T extends ConfiguredComponentBase> {
    private String                  name;
    private final ChassisBase       chassisBase;
    private final T[]               components;
    private final Efficiencies      efficiencies;
    private final List<PilotModule> modules;     // TODO: Modules should be handled as separate categories.
    private final WeaponGroups      weaponGroups;

    protected LoadoutBase(ComponentBuilder.Factory<T> aFactory, ChassisBase aChassisBase, WeaponGroups aWeaponGroups) {
        name = aChassisBase.getNameShort();
        chassisBase = aChassisBase;
        efficiencies = new Efficiencies();
        modules = new ArrayList<>();
        components = aFactory.defaultComponents(chassisBase);
        weaponGroups = aWeaponGroups;
    }

    public static XStream loadoutXstream() {
        XStream stream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
        stream.autodetectAnnotations(true);
        stream.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES);
        stream.registerConverter(new ChassiConverter());
        stream.registerConverter(new ItemConverter());
        stream.registerConverter(new ModuleConverter());
        stream.registerConverter(new ConfiguredComponentConverter(null, null));
        stream.registerConverter(new LoadoutConverter());
        stream.registerConverter(new UpgradeConverter());
        stream.registerConverter(new UpgradesConverter());
        stream.addImmutableType(Item.class);
        stream.alias("component", ConfiguredComponentStandard.class);
        stream.alias("loadout", LoadoutBase.class);
        return stream;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!getClass().isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass()))
            return false;
        LoadoutBase<T> that = getClass().cast(obj);
        if (!name.equals(that.name))
            return false;
        if (chassisBase != that.chassisBase)
            return false;
        if (!ListArrayUtils.equalsUnordered(modules, that.modules))
            return false;
        if (!Arrays.equals(components, that.components))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (getName().contains(getChassis().getNameShort()))
            return getName();
        return getName() + " (" + getChassis().getNameShort() + ")";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((chassisBase == null) ? 0 : chassisBase.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((efficiencies == null) ? 0 : efficiencies.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((components == null) ? 0 : components.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * @return An {@link Iterable} over all {@link Item}s.
     */
    public Iterable<Item> items() {
        return items(null);
    }

    /**
     * @param aClass
     *            The type to iterate over.
     * @return An {@link Iterable} over all {@link Item}s that implements <code>aClass</code>.
     */
    public <X> Iterable<X> items(Class<X> aClass) {
        return new LoadoutIterable<X>(this, aClass);
    }

    /**
     * @return The total number of armor points on this loadout.
     */
    public int getArmor() {
        int ans = 0;
        for (T component : components) {
            ans += component.getArmorTotal();
        }
        return ans;
    }

    /**
     * TODO: This should be replaced by a pilot skill tree.
     * 
     * @return The {@link Efficiencies} for this loadout.
     */
    public Efficiencies getEfficiencies() {
        return efficiencies;
    }

    /**
     * @return The {@link Engine} equipped on this loadout, or <code>null</code> if no engine is equipped.
     */
    public abstract Engine getEngine();

    /**
     * @return The mass of the loadout excluding armor. This is useful to avoid floating point precision issues from
     *         irrational armor values.
     */
    public double getMassStructItems() {
        double ans = getUpgrades().getStructure().getStructureMass(chassisBase);
        for (T component : components) {
            ans += component.getItemMass();
        }
        return ans;
    }

    /**
     * @return The current mass of the loadout.
     */
    public double getMass() {
        double ans = getMassStructItems();
        ans += getUpgrades().getArmor().getArmorMass(getArmor());
        return ans;
    }

    /**
     * @return The amount of free tonnage the loadout can still support.
     */
    public double getFreeMass() {
        double ans = chassisBase.getMassMax() - getMass();
        return ans;
    }

    /**
     * @return The base chassis of this loadout.
     */
    public ChassisBase getChassis() {
        return chassisBase;
    }

    /**
     * @return An unmodifiable {@link Collection} of all the equipped pilot modules.
     */
    public List<PilotModule> getModules() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(modules);
    }

    /**
     * @param aModuleSlot
     *            The type of module slots to get the max for.
     * @return The maximal number of modules that can be equipped on this {@link LoadoutBase}.
     */
    public abstract int getModulesMax(ModuleSlot aModuleSlot);

    /**
     * Counts the number of modules equipped of the given slot type.
     * 
     * @param aModuleSlot
     *            The {@link ModuleSlot} type to count modules of.
     * @return The number of modules.
     */
    public int getModulesOfType(ModuleSlot aModuleSlot) {
        int ans = 0;
        for (PilotModule module : getModules()) {
            if (module.getSlot() == aModuleSlot)
                ans++;
        }
        return ans;
    }

    /**
     * @param aModule
     *            The module to test if it can be added to this loadout.
     * @return A {@link EquipResult}.
     */
    public EquipResult canAddModule(PilotModule aModule) {
        if (getModules().contains(aModule))
            return EquipResult.make(EquipResultType.ModuleAlreadyEquipped);
        if (!aModule.getFaction().isCompatible(getChassis().getFaction()))
            return EquipResult.make(EquipResultType.NotSupported);

        final boolean canUseHybridSlot = aModule.getSlot() == ModuleSlot.WEAPON || aModule.getSlot() == ModuleSlot.MECH;

        final boolean isHybridSlotFree = !(getModulesOfType(ModuleSlot.MECH) > getModulesMax(ModuleSlot.MECH)
                || getModulesOfType(ModuleSlot.WEAPON) > getModulesMax(ModuleSlot.WEAPON));

        if (getModulesOfType(aModule.getSlot()) >= getModulesMax(aModule.getSlot())
                && (!canUseHybridSlot || !isHybridSlotFree))
            return EquipResult.make(EquipResultType.NotEnoughSlots);

        // TODO: Apply any additional limitations on modules
        return EquipResult.SUCCESS;
    }

    /**
     * @param aModule
     *            The {@link PilotModule} to add to this {@link LoadoutBase}.
     */
    public void addModule(PilotModule aModule) {
        modules.add(aModule);
    }

    /**
     * @param aModule
     *            The {@link PilotModule} to remove from this {@link LoadoutBase}.
     */
    public void removeModule(PilotModule aModule) {
        modules.remove(aModule);
    }

    /**
     * @return The user given name of the loadout.
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @return The number of globally available critical slots.
     */
    public int getNumCriticalSlotsFree() {
        return chassisBase.getCriticalSlotsTotal() - getNumCriticalSlotsUsed();
    }

    /**
     * @return The number of globally used critical slots.
     */
    public abstract int getNumCriticalSlotsUsed();

    /**
     * @param aLocation
     *            The location to get the component for.
     * @return The component at the given location
     */
    public T getComponent(Location aLocation) {
        return components[aLocation.ordinal()];
    }

    /**
     * @return A {@link Collection} of all the configured components.
     */
    public Collection<T> getComponents() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(components));
    }

    /**
     * @return The {@link Upgrades} that are equipped on this loadout.
     */
    public abstract Upgrades getUpgrades();

    /**
     * @param aHardpointType
     *            The type of hard points to count.
     * @return The number of hard points of the given type.
     */
    public int getHardpointsCount(HardPointType aHardpointType) {
        // Note: This has been moved from chassis base because for omnimechs, the hard point count depends on which
        // omnipods are equipped.
        int sum = 0;
        for (T component : components) {
            sum += component.getHardPointCount(aHardpointType);
        }
        return sum;
    }

    /**
     * @return The maximal number of jump jets the loadout can support.
     */
    abstract public int getJumpJetsMax();

    /**
     * @return The total number of heat sinks equipped.
     */
    public int getHeatsinksCount() {
        int ans = countItemsOfType(HeatSink.class);

        Engine engine = getEngine();
        if (engine != null) {
            ans += engine.getNumInternalHeatsinks();
        }

        return ans;
    }

    private int countItemsOfType(Class<?> aClass) {
        int ans = 0;
        Iterator<?> it = items(aClass).iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            ans++;
            it.next();
        }
        return ans;
    }

    /**
     * @return The total number of jump jets equipped.
     */
    public int getJumpJetCount() {
        return countItemsOfType(JumpJet.class);
    }

    /**
     * Gets a {@link List} of {@link ConfiguredComponentBase}s that could possibly house the given item.
     * <p>
     * This method checks necessary but not sufficient constraints. In other words, the {@link ConfiguredComponentBase}s
     * in the returned list may or may not be able to hold the {@link Item}. But the {@link ConfiguredComponentBase}s
     * not in the list are unable to hold the {@link Item}.
     * <p>
     * This method is mainly useful for limiting search spaces for various optimization algorithms.
     * 
     * @param aItem
     *            The {@link Item} to find candidate {@link ConfiguredComponentBase}s for.
     * @return A {@link List} of {@link ConfiguredComponentBase}s that might be able to hold the {@link Item}.
     */
    public List<ConfiguredComponentBase> getCandidateLocationsForItem(Item aItem) {
        List<ConfiguredComponentBase> candidates = new ArrayList<>();
        if (EquipResult.SUCCESS != canEquipGlobal(aItem))
            return candidates;

        int globalFreeHardPoints = 0;
        HardPointType hardpointType = aItem.getHardpointType();

        for (ConfiguredComponentBase part : components) {
            ComponentBase internal = part.getInternalComponent();
            if (internal.isAllowed(aItem, getEngine())) {
                if (aItem.getHardpointType() != HardPointType.NONE && part.getHardPointCount(hardpointType) < 1) {
                    continue;
                }
                candidates.add(part);
            }

            if (hardpointType != HardPointType.NONE) {
                final int localFreeHardPoints = part.getHardPointCount(hardpointType)
                        - part.getItemsOfHardpointType(hardpointType);
                globalFreeHardPoints += localFreeHardPoints;
            }
        }

        if (hardpointType != HardPointType.NONE && globalFreeHardPoints <= 0) {
            candidates.clear();
        }

        return candidates;
    }

    /**
     * Changes the name of the loadout.
     * 
     * @param aNewName
     *            The new name of the loadout.
     */
    public void rename(String aNewName) {
        name = aNewName;
    }

    /**
     * Checks global constraints that could prevent the item from being added to this {@link LoadoutStandard}.
     * <p>
     * This includes:
     * <ul>
     * <li>Only one engine.</li>
     * <li>Max jump jet count not exceeded.</li>
     * <li>Correct jump jet type.</li>
     * <li>Enough free mass.</li>
     * <li>Enough globally free critical slots.</li>
     * <li>Enough globally free hard points of applicable type.</li>
     * </ul>
     * 
     * @param aItem
     *            The {@link Item} to check for.
     * @return <code>true</code> if the given {@link Item} is globally feasible on this loadout.
     */
    public EquipResult canEquip(Item aItem) {
        EquipResult globalResult = canEquipGlobal(aItem);

        if (globalResult != EquipResult.SUCCESS) {
            // The case where adding a weapon that would cause LAA/HA to be removed will not cause an issue as omnimechs
            // where this can occur, have fixed armor and structure slots.
            return globalResult;
        }

        if (aItem instanceof Engine) {
            Engine engine = (Engine) aItem;
            if (engine.getType() == EngineType.XL) {
                final int sideSlots = engine.getSide().getNumCriticalSlots();
                if (getComponent(Location.LeftTorso).getSlotsFree() < sideSlots) {
                    return EquipResult.make(Location.LeftTorso, EquipResultType.NotEnoughSlotsForXLSide);
                }
                if (getComponent(Location.RightTorso).getSlotsFree() < sideSlots) {
                    return EquipResult.make(Location.RightTorso, EquipResultType.NotEnoughSlotsForXLSide);
                }
            }
            return getComponent(Location.CenterTorso).canEquip(engine);
        }

        EquipResult reason = EquipResult.SUCCESS;
        for (ConfiguredComponentBase part : getComponents()) {
            EquipResult componentResult = part.canEquip(aItem);
            if (componentResult == EquipResult.SUCCESS)
                return componentResult;
            if (componentResult.isMoreSpecificThan(reason)) {
                reason = componentResult;
            }
        }
        return reason;
    }

    /**
     * Checks only global constraints against the {@link Item}. These are necessary but not sufficient conditions. Local
     * conditions are needed to be sufficient.
     * 
     * @param aItem
     *            The {@link Item} to check.
     * @return <code>true</code> if the necessary checks are passed.
     */
    protected EquipResult canEquipGlobal(Item aItem) {
        if (!getChassis().isAllowed(aItem))
            return EquipResult.make(EquipResultType.NotSupported);
        if (aItem.getMass() > getFreeMass())
            return EquipResult.make(EquipResultType.TooHeavy);
        if (!aItem.isCompatible(getUpgrades()))
            return EquipResult.make(EquipResultType.IncompatibleUpgrades);

        if (aItem instanceof JumpJet && getJumpJetsMax() - getJumpJetCount() < 1)
            return EquipResult.make(EquipResultType.JumpJetCapacityReached);

        // Allow engine slot heat sinks as long as there is enough free mass.
        ConfiguredComponentBase ct = getComponent(Location.CenterTorso);
        if (aItem instanceof HeatSink && ct.getEngineHeatsinks() < ct.getEngineHeatsinksMax())
            return EquipResult.SUCCESS;

        // FIXME: The case where adding a weapon that would cause LAA/HA to be removed
        // while at max global slots fails even if it might succeed.

        int requiredSlots = aItem.getNumCriticalSlots();
        if (aItem instanceof Engine) {
            if (getEngine() != null) {
                return EquipResult.make(EquipResultType.EngineAlreadyEquipped);
            }

            Engine engine = (Engine) aItem;
            if (engine.getType() == EngineType.XL) {
                requiredSlots += 2 * engine.getSide().getNumCriticalSlots();
            }
        }

        if (requiredSlots > getNumCriticalSlotsFree())
            return EquipResult.make(EquipResultType.NotEnoughSlots);
        return EquipResult.SUCCESS;
    }

    public MovementProfile getMovementProfile() {
        return getChassis().getMovementProfileBase();
    }

    /**
     * @return A String containing a HTML formatted summary of the quirks for this loadout.
     */
    public abstract String getQuirkHtmlSummary();

    /**
     * Returns a {@link Collection} of all equipment or modules or omnipods or quirks that are modifiers.
     * 
     * @return The {@link Collection} of modifiers.
     */
    public Collection<Modifier> getModifiers() {
        List<Modifier> modifiers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ModifierEquipment t : items(ModifierEquipment.class)) {
            modifiers.addAll(t.getModifiers());
        }
        for (PilotModule module : getModules()) {
            if (module instanceof ModifierEquipment) {
                modifiers.addAll(((ModifierEquipment) module).getModifiers());
            }
        }
        modifiers.addAll(getEfficiencies().getModifiers());
        return modifiers;
    }

    /**
     * @return The {@link WeaponGroups} for this {@link LoadoutBase}.
     */
    public WeaponGroups getWeaponGroups() {
        return weaponGroups;
    }
}
```

> LoadoutStandard.java

```
/**
 * This class represents the complete state of a 'mechs configuration.
 * 
 * @author Emily Björk
 */
public class LoadoutStandard extends LoadoutBase<ConfiguredComponentStandard> {
    private final UpgradesMutable upgrades;

    @Deprecated
    public static LoadoutStandard load(File aFile) {
        XStream stream = loadoutXstream();
        return (LoadoutStandard) stream.fromXML(aFile);
    }

    /**
     * Will create a new, empty load out based on the given chassis.
     * 
     * @param aFactory
     *            The {@link Factory} used to construct the components.
     * 
     * @param aChassi
     *            The chassis to base the load out on.
     * @param aUpgradesMutable
     *            The {@link UpgradesMutable} that will be used for this chassis.
     * @param aWeaponGroups
     */
    LoadoutStandard(Factory<ConfiguredComponentStandard> aFactory, ChassisStandard aChassi,
            UpgradesMutable aUpgradesMutable, WeaponGroups aWeaponGroups) {
        super(aFactory, aChassi, aWeaponGroups);

        upgrades = aUpgradesMutable;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = prime * result + upgrades.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!super.equals(obj))
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof LoadoutStandard))
            return false;
        LoadoutStandard other = (LoadoutStandard) obj;
        if (!upgrades.equals(other.upgrades))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public ChassisStandard getChassis() {
        return (ChassisStandard) super.getChassis();
    }

    /**
     * @return The {@link Engine} equipped on this loadout, or <code>null</code> if no engine is equipped.
     */
    @Override
    public Engine getEngine() {
        // The engine is not among the fixed items for a standard loadout.
        for (Item item : getComponent(Location.CenterTorso).getItemsEquipped()) {
            if (item instanceof Engine) {
                return (Engine) item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumCriticalSlotsUsed() {
        int ans = getUpgrades().getStructure().getExtraSlots() + getUpgrades().getArmor().getExtraSlots();
        for (ConfiguredComponentStandard component : getComponents()) {
            ans += component.getSlotsUsed();
        }
        return ans;
    }

    @Override
    public int getJumpJetsMax() {
        return getChassis().getJumpJetsMax();
    }

    @Override
    public UpgradesMutable getUpgrades() {
        return upgrades;
    }

    @Override
    public int getModulesMax(ModuleSlot aModuleSlot) {
        if (aModuleSlot == ModuleSlot.MECH) {
            return getChassis().getMechModulesMax();
        }
        else if (aModuleSlot == ModuleSlot.CONSUMABLE) {
            return getChassis().getConsumableModulesMax();
        }
        else if (aModuleSlot == ModuleSlot.WEAPON) {
            return getChassis().getWeaponModulesMax();
        }
        else if (aModuleSlot == ModuleSlot.HYBRID) {
            return 1;// 1 from mastery
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown module slot type!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Modifier> getModifiers() {
        Collection<Modifier> ans = super.getModifiers();
        ans.addAll(getChassis().getQuirks());
        return ans;
    }

    @Override
    public String getQuirkHtmlSummary() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("<html>");
        sb.append("<body>");

        sb.append("<p>Chassis Quirks:</p>");
        for (Modifier modifier : getChassis().getQuirks()) {
            modifier.describeToHtml(sb);
        }

        sb.append("<p>Equipment Bonuses:</p>");
        for (ModifierEquipment me : items(ModifierEquipment.class)) {
            for (Modifier modifier : me.getModifiers()) {
                modifier.describeToHtml(sb);
            }
        }

        sb.append("<p>Module Bonuses:</p>");
        for (PilotModule me : getModules()) {
            if (me instanceof ModifierEquipment) {
                for (Modifier modifier : ((ModifierEquipment) me).getModifiers()) {
                    modifier.describeToHtml(sb);
                }
            }
        }

        sb.append("</body>");
        sb.append("</html>");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

> LoadoutOmniMech.java

```
/**
 * This class represents a configured loadout for an omnimech.
 * 
 * @author Emily Björk
 */
public class LoadoutOmniMech extends LoadoutBase<ConfiguredComponentOmniMech> {
    transient private final Upgrades upgrades;

    /**
     * Creates a new, empty loadout.
     * 
     * @param aFactory
     *            The {@link Factory} used to construct the components.
     * @param aChassis
     *            The chassis to base this loadout on.
     * @param aUpgrades
     *            The upgrades to use.
     * @param aWeaponGroups
     *            The weapon groups object for this loadout.
     */
    LoadoutOmniMech(Factory<ConfiguredComponentOmniMech> aFactory, ChassisOmniMech aChassis, Upgrades aUpgrades,
            WeaponGroups aWeaponGroups) {
        super(aFactory, aChassis, aWeaponGroups);
        upgrades = aUpgrades;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = prime * result + ((upgrades == null) ? 0 : upgrades.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!super.equals(obj))
            return false;
        LoadoutOmniMech other = (LoadoutOmniMech) obj;
        if (!upgrades.equals(other.upgrades))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * This setter method is only intended to be used from package local {@link Command}s. It's a raw, unchecked
     * accessor.
     * 
     * @param aOmniPod
     *            The omnipod to set, it's put in it's dedicated slot.
     */
    public void setOmniPod(OmniPod aOmniPod) {
        ConfiguredComponentOmniMech component = getComponent(aOmniPod.getLocation());
        component.setOmniPod(aOmniPod);
    }

    @Override
    public int getJumpJetsMax() {
        int ans = getChassis().getFixedJumpJets();
        for (ConfiguredComponentOmniMech component : getComponents()) {
            ans += component.getOmniPod().getJumpJetsMax();
        }
        return ans;
    }

    @Override
    public ChassisOmniMech getChassis() {
        return (ChassisOmniMech) super.getChassis();
    }

    @Override
    public Engine getEngine() {
        return getChassis().getFixedEngine();
    }

    /**
     * @return The number of globally used critical slots.
     */
    @Override
    public int getNumCriticalSlotsUsed() {
        int ans = 0;
        for (ConfiguredComponentOmniMech component : getComponents()) {
            ans += component.getSlotsUsed();
        }
        return ans;
    }

    @Override
    public Upgrades getUpgrades() {
        return upgrades;
    }

    @Override
    public int getModulesMax(ModuleSlot aModuleSlot) {
        if (aModuleSlot == ModuleSlot.MECH) {
            int ans = getChassis().getMechModulesMax();
            for (ConfiguredComponentOmniMech component : getComponents()) {
                ans += component.getOmniPod().getPilotModulesMax();
            }
            return ans;
        }
        else if (aModuleSlot == ModuleSlot.CONSUMABLE) {
            return getChassis().getConsumableModulesMax();
        }
        else if (aModuleSlot == ModuleSlot.WEAPON) {
            return getChassis().getWeaponModulesMax();
        }
        else if (aModuleSlot == ModuleSlot.HYBRID) {
            return 1; // +1 for mastery
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown module slot type!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Modifier> getModifiers() {
        Collection<Modifier> ans = super.getModifiers();
        for (ConfiguredComponentOmniMech component : getComponents()) {
            ans.addAll(component.getOmniPod().getQuirks());
        }
        return ans;
    }

    @Override
    public String getQuirkHtmlSummary() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("<html>");
        sb.append("<body>");

        sb.append("<p>Omnipod Quirks:</p>");
        for (ConfiguredComponentOmniMech component : getComponents()) {
            for (Modifier modifier : component.getOmniPod().getQuirks()) {
                modifier.describeToHtml(sb);
            }
        }

        sb.append("<p>Equipment Bonuses:</p>");
        for (ModifierEquipment me : items(ModifierEquipment.class)) {
            for (Modifier modifier : me.getModifiers()) {
                modifier.describeToHtml(sb);
            }
        }

        sb.append("<p>Module Bonuses:</p>");
        for (PilotModule me : getModules()) {
            if (me instanceof ModifierEquipment) {
                for (Modifier modifier : ((ModifierEquipment) me).getModifiers()) {
                    modifier.describeToHtml(sb);
                }
            }
        }

        sb.append("</body>");
        sb.append("</html>");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

As you can see there are some attempts at using Dependency Injection, which I learned of about 1 year into the project. There exists a factory for building loadouts, but it's not that well developed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code amount is substantial. So you need to refactor in small steps in order not to break everything.

If a class has grown organically large, it probably has to many responsibilities. Identify those and move them out.

For example, `loadoutXstream` seems like some sort of serialization method. Serialization is an orthogonal concern and should be moved out of a class whenever possible. The fact that it's static is both an indication and also makes it easy to move it out.

Keeping with the static topic, some methods are practically static. Public methods that do not implement a (necessarily) abstract method from a super type, which need not have intimate knowledge of the private fields, but instead interacts with its class through its public interface; namely a low-cohesion method; is a method that exhibits all tenets of a static method but is not made one.

Take a look at how I started to change `canAddModule` method:

```
public EquipResult canAddModule(PilotModule aModule) {
    if (getModules().contains(aModule))
        return EquipResult.make(EquipResultType.ModuleAlreadyEquipped);
    if (!aModule.getFaction().isCompatible(getChassis().getFaction()))
        return EquipResult.make(EquipResultType.NotSupported);

    boolean notEnoughSlots = new SlotCapacityPolicy().notSatisfied(this, aModule);
    if (notEnoughSlots)
        return EquipResult.make(EquipResultType.NotEnoughSlots);

    // TODO: Apply any additional limitations on modules
    return EquipResult.SUCCESS;
}

public static class SlotCapacityPolicy {
    public boolean notSatisfied(LoadoutBase<?> loadout, PilotModule module) {
        final boolean canUseHybridSlot = module.getSlot() == ModuleSlot.WEAPON || module.getSlot() == ModuleSlot.MECH;

        final boolean isHybridSlotFree = !(loadout.getModulesOfType(ModuleSlot.MECH) > loadout.getModulesMax(ModuleSlot.MECH)
                || loadout.getModulesOfType(ModuleSlot.WEAPON) > loadout.getModulesMax(ModuleSlot.WEAPON));

        boolean notEnoughSlots = loadout.getModulesOfType(module.getSlot()) >= loadout.getModulesMax(module.getSlot())
                && (!canUseHybridSlot || !isHybridSlotFree);

        return notEnoughSlots;
    }
}
```

If you keep moving things out, you can change this:

```
EquipResult.SUCCESS == currentLoadout.canAddModule(module)
```

to this:

```
rules.canAddModule(currentLoadout, module)
```

`getQuirkHtmlSummary` is view logic  (and evidently so is `modifier.describeToHtml(sb)`), and just as serialization logic, should be moved out of the model class. Because it's abstract, it requires different techniques to be removed. You can construct a Loadout in a factory using [component](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html)s. In this case one such component would be `StandardHtmlRenderingStrategy` or `OmniSomethingHtmlRenderingStrategy`. Or you can lookup loadout rendering strategy at runtime for a given loadout. (just as `abstract` does, but explicitly)

Eventually, instead of `loadout.getQuirkHtmlSummary()` do a `quirksRenderer.render(loadout)`.

Comment: I like the policy idea, but rather than constructing on-the-spot I could inject it in the constructor. I have recently begun converting the code to use a factory for loadout construction so this would be a good step in the direction that I want to go with inversion of control. Great review, thank you!

Comment: Constructor injection is what I would go towards, too. That's why I said "how I started to change". Because there is already a significant code base you have to keep refactoring steps trivial. Another step would be extract the interface of the policies (`ModuleAdditionPolicy` and `ItemEquippingPolicy`).You can make these extend [Java8's `BiPredicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiPredicate.html) or you can implement [Specification pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) by hand. So they are composable.